# How to save a session on a website indefinitively and use it on a web scraping bot

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, session, jwt, bots

I was wondering if there was a way to manually authenticate into a website and then save your session be it with the cookies of the website itself or just the browser session.

I am using **JsNode** and **Puppeteer** but open to other suggestions.

My end goal would be to create a bot that would log into that session daily execute a couple of tasks and then leave, ideally I would host this in a small server or my computer.
Thanks for any help

I have tried using browser session following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxXjDRyOeBg
however, this wouldnt work as anytime the browser is closed, the sessions is lost. Also, can't seem to run it on headless.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).